# Why is Googlebot unable to reach URLs that are valid and reachable?

Tags: linux, networking, debian

For a while, I had a problem with Googlebot being unable to crawl my site (and in fact I was having this problem for so long that my site was actually de-listed from Google).

Testing my site in Google Webmaster Tools with Fetch As Googlebot actually returned a blank page: Googlebot was unable to reach my site, and could provide no diagnostic message that could explain the lack of reachability.

What’s up with that?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, for reasons still unknown, my correctly-configured networking service on my web server was bringing up its IP address with a `/8` netmask, instead of the (in my case) correct netmask of `/24`.

Manually removing the offending entry from my server’s routing table and adding the correct entry resolved the issue, and Googlebot is now happily visiting my web server again:

```
root@web:/# ip addr show eth0
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    inet 192.0.2.7/8 brd 192.255.255.255 scope global eth0
root@web:/# ip addr add 192.0.2.7/24 dev eth0
root@web:/# ip addr del 192.0.2.7/8 dev eth0
root@web:/# ip addr show eth0
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    inet 192.0.2.7/24 scope global eth0
```

(IP addresses changed to protect the innocent. Adding the correct entry before removing the incorrect one helps keep your SSH session open if you’re connected via that address.)